# JQM how to add A background Image to a Themeroller template

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created a mobile website using the JQM themeroller

http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1/

Now i have tried everything i know to ad a background image, but no matter how i try, it doesn't wanna show up....

What is the best way to get a background image to show up?

Thanks

dave

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it like this:

```
body.ui-mobile-viewport,div.ui-mobile-viewport {
    background-color:   transparent;
    background-image:   url("your_image_URL");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess its a CSS property that has background image set.